# Constructing $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$ using Dedekind Sections/cuts.

Tags: real-analysis

I'll try to present my understanding of construction of $\mathbb R$ and request your help in doubts that I have in the same. 
So we consider a straight line $\Gamma$ and mark origin (reference point) on it as $O$, we'll measure all distances (length/taxi-cab distances) from $0$. We mark integers on it and call the set of as $\mathbb Z$. This set $\mathbb Z$ does not form a field.
Assuming that we can fill the line using only integers has problems as then nothing lies in between integers $n$ and $n+1$, which makes the line full of "gaps".   We do not have an integral solution to equations like $2x+1=0,2x+3=0$ etc. 
Nos. of the form $p/q:q\ne 0$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ (Let's call this set the set of rationals and denote it by $\mathbb Q$ and it includes $0$ when $q=0$) can be placed in the gaps and we may hope that now the line will be completely filled  using elements of $\mathbb Q$. It is to be noted that $\mathbb Q$ forms a field.

Now another problem arises. There is no rational number $x$ which solves $x^2=2$. It seems that still there are some gaps in our line $\Gamma$. **But why? Suppose that Geometry (in particular right angled triangle) is not known, why does this equation have to be solvable?What happens if real line consists of only $\mathbb Q$.**

Now let's try to use Dedekind construction of $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be two mutually exclusive properties exactly one of which must be possessed by every rational number. Let $P$ be the property "less than 2" and $Q$ the property "greater than 2" i.e. if $x\in Q$ then either $x^2\lt 2$ or $x^2\gt 2$. Let $L\subset \mathbb Q$ be such that $L=\{x\in \mathbb Q:x^2\lt 2\}$ and $R=\{x\in \mathbb Q:x^2\gt 2\}$. 
It can be shown that $L$ does not have its greatest member and $R$ does not have its least element in it. **My question is now without geometric intuition why boundary separating $L$ and $R$ should exist?** **Why should $x$ exist such that $x^2=2$?** 
If the above is clear then it can be shown that dedekind cuts/sections corresponding to every $t$ (rational or not), will satisfy field axioms and thus we'll have a new field and name it $\mathbb R$. 
**Dedekind cuts/sections' definition**: This is the way I understand it is that there are two mutually exclusive properties $P$ and $Q$ exactly one of which should be possessed by every rational number. So as above $L$ and $R$ for $x^2=2$ form dedekind sections/cuts. The sets $\{x:x^2\lt 4\}$ and $\{x:x^2\gt 4\}$ do not form dedekind cuts as $2$ belongs to neither of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask:

> Suppose that Geometry (in particular right angled triangle) is not known, why does this equation have to be solvable?What happens if real line consists of only $\mathbb Q$? [...] Without geometric intuition why boundary separating $L$ and $R$ should exist? Why should $x$ exist such that $x^2=2$?

Well first of all let me push back against the question itself. Geometric intuition is *exactly* what motivates the Dedekind cut construction. The idea is that we're looking for an algebraic structure which captures some very simple geometric properties of the "ideal line" (key amongst them being *connectedness*); if we stop caring about those geometric properties, then of course there's no particular reason to keep looking for the same sort of structure! There's certainly nothing wrong with not being particularly interested in geometry and considering $\mathbb{Q}$ to be the "right" number system. (If you can say more about *why* you want to get away from the geometric motivation of $\mathbb{R}$, I can probably be more satisfying with this section.)

That said, though, one of the major themes in mathematics is the power of abstract concepts to clarify concrete ideas. For example, we see this in **analytic number theory**, where results about integers are proved intuitively and naturally by considering things related to $\mathbb{R}$. So even if geometric intuition isn't something you care about a priori, you should still care about it as a kind of "new-mathematics-generator" in general.

---

Separately, I think the following theorem will help clarify the "essentially geometric" flavor of the construction of $\mathbb{R}$:

> Up to isomorphism, there is exactly one connected ordered abelian group.

Here "abelian group" basically means a collection of things we can add and subtract, where addition is commutative. Think (signed) *lengths*, as represented by (directed) *line segments*. "Ordered" means [what it sounds like (if a bit technically)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group), and "connected" is the new geometric idea. "Isomorphism" is basically a notion of "sameness" - think about how all the different constructions of the reals (Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences, [etc.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03467.pdf)) still wind up producing "basically the same thing."

If we replace the connectedness requirement with something weaker, then suddenly there are **tons** of possibilities. Besides things like $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ we also have weirder objects - say, the set of polynomials in a single variable $x$ with rational coefficients, ordered by setting $p\trianglelefteq q\iff \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} p(x)\le\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}q(x).$ So connectedness plays a crucial role in pinning down a *unique* number system for us to work with. Even if you're not wedded to it, or geometric intuition more generally, as a foundational idea, this is a huge sign that it's mathematically significant: it's generally worth understanding simple-sounding hypotheses which suddenly wind up picking out a single object from a gigantic class of objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifications . So basically we are creating an object using Dedekind cuts/sections that just happens to be a field and satisfies us geometrically as well and hence leaves no "gaps" on the line. In other words, every element of this newly found field corresponds uniquely to a point on the line and we call this newly found field as $\mathbb R$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Koro Well, I'm not sure I'd use the phrase "just happens," but yes, that's substantively correct. You can think of it as having a bunch of different ideas about what a number system should be like, and finding a process which builds a number system satisfying ... well, maybe not *all* of them, but at least *lots* of them. Keep in mind that there are also lots of other number systems out there too - besides the relatively-straightforward $\mathbb{C}$ there are also the **p-adic numbers** (for $p$ prime), denoted "$\mathbb{Q}_p$," which can be thought of as "alternate $\mathbb{R}$s" in a sense.

Comment: Moral: it's a rich and wild world out there, and you should take as many algebraic structures with you as you can!

Comment: Rich and wild! Yes  I think so too. There’s this one more thing that I’m starting to wonder about. Irrationals solve the problems like $x^2=2$ and are incorporated in set of reals with the result that now the line has no gaps. Then again, why didn’t anybody claim that still there are some gaps left and this is because $x^2+1=0$ is not solvable on $\mathbb R$ so it seems that still there are some gaps (on the line) unoccupied? Complex nos. should fit in those gaps. It seems so wrong but this question probably males sense. I’ll request your clarification in my this doubt also please.

Comment: @Koro It depends what we mean by "gap." *Geometrically* speaking, the lack of a solution to $x^2+1=0$ doesn't represent a "hole" in the *line*; we can make this precise by proving e.g. that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected (in the precise sense of topology). Passing from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ isn't really like filling in holes, but rather adding a dimension (think "complex *plane*" vs. "real *line*").

Comment: To check whether an unsolvable equation corresponds to a "hole in $\mathbb{Q}$," we need to look at its "approximate solutions." Take $x^2-2=0$ first. For every $\epsilon>0$ there is some rational $p$ such that $\vert p^2-2\vert<\epsilon$ (a good exercise). However, this fails for $x^2+1=0$: there is no rational $p$ such that $\vert p^2+1\vert<1$. This means that we can "walk towards the missing point in $\mathbb{Q}$" in the first case, but in the second case we need to "walk away from $\mathbb{Q}$ altogether." This may not be very helpful at first - but it is getting at the topological issue.

Comment: So connectedness is the key here. We need to walk not just away from Q rather R itself in case of $x^2+1=0.$ Thanks a lot  I understand it now.

Comment: @Koro: if you think that solution to polynomial equations is the motivation behind extension of $\mathbb{Q} $ to $\mathbb{R} $ then you are mistaken. The idea is more related to order relations in a field and it is desirable that that the order relations are *complete*. The order relations on integers is complete (any set of integers bounded above has a maximum). The solution of polynomials is so smartly handled by algebra (algebraic extensions).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I really don't think that root of polynomial equation is the only motivation behind extension of $Q$ to $R$. My understanding now is that we have created a new object using Dedekind cuts (there may be other methods also) that satisfies order relations, has supremum property and satisfies field axioms (AMD). This new object is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Koro: Perhaps I misinterpreted and if that's the case, sorry. Your question seemed more focused on why should equations like $x^2=2$ have a solution unless we need it for geometry. Motivation for geometric / algebraic needs is easy to introduce, but I find the idea of complete order relations as more satisfying.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I am happy that I understood the answer to my question. You people here help me a lot.  And I'm very grateful to all of you for your support.